# Can't get sed to insert an `\n`

Tags: bash, sed, substitution

Based on other posts here, I can add a newline using

```
echo "aaaaCellaaaCellaa" | sed -r 's:(Cell):\n\1:g'
```

both from the command line and as part of a script. However, when I try to use that snippet in the actual script I'm working on

```
newdata="$(iwlist wlan0 scanning)"
newstring="$(echo $newdata | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -s [:space:] | sed -r 's/(Cell)/\n\1/g' | sed -e 's:Channel\::Channel=:g' | sed -e 's: :=:g')"
echo $newstring
```

the `\n` is ignored and I get one long line (with a single space before each "Cell").

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

[BashPitfalls #14 aka `echo $foo` aka Quote Your Variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo):

```
$ echo "$newstring"
```

.

```
$ foo=$'foo\nbar'
$ echo ${foo}
foo bar
$ echo "${foo}"
foo
bar
```

EDIT:

```
$ cat t.txt
Cell 01 - Address: AB:CD:EF:12:34:56
          ESSID:"name1"
          Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
          Mode:master
          Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
          Encryption key:on

Cell 02 - Address: AB:CD:EF:12:34:56
          ESSID:"name2"
          Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
          Mode:master
          Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
          Encryption key:on
```

.

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

newdata="$(< t.txt)"
newstring="$(echo $newdata | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -s [:space:] | sed -r 's/(Cell)/\n\1/g' | sed -e 's:Channel\::Channel=:g' | sed -e 's: :=:g')"
echo "$newstring"
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh

Cell=01=-=Address:=AB:CD:EF:12:34:56=ESSID:"name1"=Protocol:IEEE=802.11g=Mode:master=Frequency:2.417=GHz=(Channel=2)=Encryption=key:on=
Cell=02=-=Address:=AB:CD:EF:12:34:56=ESSID:"name2"=Protocol:IEEE=802.11g=Mode:master=Frequency:2.417=GHz=(Channel=2)=Encryption=key:on=
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example certainly illustrates your point, but even moving to echo  "${newdata}" in my script, I'm still unable to get a newline. And printf was no better.

Comment: @dlanced I don't have a Linux box with a WiFi card handy but if the output looks like in my edit your code works for me (even though it can be improved, but that's besides the point for now) unless I am missing something?

Comment: Your example worked for me too. Perhaps the trouble lies in the way iwlist delivers its raw data. I could always cat to a disk file and echo from there, but I'm going to be using a cheap solid state drive and I want to limit the writes (this script will be run every few minutes).

Comment: You got me thinking in the right direction: it turns out the problem was with my final echo $newstring which, unlike your correct version, lacked quotation marks! Thanks!

Comment: @dlanced This was exactly the point of my answer as is obvious from both my example at the top as well as the link I provided ;-)

Comment: Given what we know about the semantics of `echo $var`, the 2 trs in : `echo $newdata | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -s [:space:]` will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "aaaaCellaaaCellaa" | sed -r 's:(Cell):\
\1:g'
```

\n is not avaialble in replacement pattern. Another way is to capture it from search pattern and use a group replacement in second pattern like

```
sed 'H;x;s/\(\n\)\(sample group top keep\)other stuff/\2\1/'
```

but not working with /g, you need a loop for that.

Comment: This is not correct, `sed 's/foo/\n/'` works as expected and it has already been determined that it was a quoting issue.

Comment: depend on system, work on linux bash gnu sed that is only part of sed unix world. Echo is not relevant here because \n is inserted after the echo occur (pipe) so no more interpretation due to quote.

Comment: I stand corrected, not all versions of `sed` allow this since it's not required by POSIX (it doesn't have anything to do with `bash` though, `bash` doesn't touch the single-quoted string). `busybox sed` allows this as well, but I don't have other implementations at hand to test. However, this particular problem *was* due to quoting where `echo $newstring` is subject to word splitting whereas `echo "$newstring"` is not. Without quotes the first character in `$IFS` is used to join the output together which, by default, is a space.

Comment: right (+1), but problem is solve with my command (test on my cygwin, on my aix [without the -r]) avoiding the quote issue. Now, if it is only adding a new line for output on terminal and not modifying the content itself, quote is the issue (but not the requested question in this case)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem was using 
     echo $newstring
to print my output, leaving out the quotation marks (that Adrian instinctively included in his example). It should be:
    echo "$newstring"